# Sums of representations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

I was trying to prove this question:

**Prove that $(T_{1} + T_{2}) S \simeq T_{1}S +  T_{2}S $ for any representations $T_{1},T_{2},$ and $S$ of $G$.**

So I was reading the Sums of representations and I found that it is description in terms of matrices is as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Can I say by this that addition of representations can be considered as a diagonal matrix, but why? this idea is so hard for me to believe, can anyone give me a numeric example please?

Comment: The matrix is block diagonal, not diagonal. Also, you are trying to prove that $$(V_1\oplus V_2)\otimes W\cong (V_1\otimes W)\oplus(V_2\otimes W)$$ as $G$-modules.

Comment: why you said that it is block diagonal and not diagonal?

Comment: Because I am trying to help you. Each $T(g)_{(e)_i}$ is a $(\dim V_i)\times(\dim V_i)$ matrix.

Comment: The definition of the product of two representations is found here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102342/comparing-the-representation-t-otimes-t-in-terms-of-matrices-and-t2?rq=1 @DavidHill  ..... according to the definition in the link are you still suggesting that I should proof the equivalence that you mentioned above?

Comment: Are you saying that we are proving this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805019/distributivity-of-tensor-products-over-direct-sums-for-group-representations @DavidHill

Comment: Yes. That is an equivalent formulation of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The proof mentioned in the link above is difficult could you please explain it in a simpler way @DavidHill

Comment: https://arbourj.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/distributivity-of-tensor-product-over-direct-sum/  I have also found the solution in this link but I have a difficulty in understanding why the given map there is bilinear (as mentioned by the writer) and what is  the universal property of modules @DavidHill

Comment: by the way I understood what is the universal property of tensor product of modules but I have difficulty in showing that the two maps in the given link above are bilinear @DavidHill